# Unificar 2 registros en un solo registro SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
 SELECT ID_ER_CONCEPTO_PPTO, banorte, aspe
     FROM #TBL_PASO_1
```

Con este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de unificar estos registros para que se muestren de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que las columnas no deben de tener el mismo nombre pero, esa parte ya la estoy resoliviendo.

Comment: emmm....entonces habría que inventar el Id concepto?, cuál es la lógica a usar para eso?

Comment: ¿De donde sale el otro ID_ER_CONCEPTO_PPTO?¿Siempre serán 2 valores o son más?

Comment: El concepto lo obtendria de un catalogo de conceptos, en ocaciones pueden ser mas de dos valores, lo unico en lo que tengo duda es como unificarlos para que se puedan crear las nuevas columnas

Comment: ¿Los quieres _unificar_ dentro de la tabla o que se muestre un único registro en una consulta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más fácil en mi opinión, es construir una tabla de relaciones, que puede tener dos o más relaciones, que habrá que explotar luego. Por ejemplo:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT 111 as ID_ER_CONCEPTO_PPTO,
          109 as ID_ER_CONCEPTO_PPTO_1,
          110 as ID_ER_CONCEPTO_PPTO_2
)

SELECT T.ID_ER_CONCEPTO_PPTO,
       T1.banorte,
       T1.aspe,
       T2.banorte,
       T2.aspe
       FROM CTE T
       INNER JOIN #TBL_PASO_1 T1
          ON T1.ID_ER_CONCEPTO_PPTO = T.ID_ER_CONCEPTO_PPTO_1
       INNER JOIN #TBL_PASO_1 T2
          ON T2.ID_ER_CONCEPTO_PPTO = T.ID_ER_CONCEPTO_PPTO_2
```

Lo fundamenta es definir justamente la relaciones, que incluso podría ser una tabla física, en este ejemplo la definimos "al vuelo" mediante un [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) pero también podría ser una subconsulta:

```
SELECT 111 as ID_ER_CONCEPTO_PPTO,
       109 as ID_ER_CONCEPTO_PPTO_1,
       110 as ID_ER_CONCEPTO_PPTO_2
```

Básicamente el nuevo `ID` y una columna por cada `ID` relacionado, luego simplemente es cuestión de hacer los `JOINs` adecuados para transformar las filas en columnas.